# Reinvent the “import random” feature

Tags: python

I am making a Rock Paper Scissors game but I can’t use the import random and I do not know how reinvent it, I have a idea how and that is using percentages like there is a 33% chance to throw rock and 33% for every other throw but I cannot use the import random feature! Any help???

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include the code you've written to solve the problem.

Comment: Why can't you use `import random`? Can you import other modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the time when the program/function starts to run, divide it by 3 and check the remainder:

```
import time
x = int(time.time())
a = x % 3
```

`a` has 1/3 probability to be either 0, 1 or 2.